# How to apply the same percentage to a whole column?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc, I have data in one column. I need to calculate the percentage of a whole column of data without filling the percentage column one by one, without writing the formula one by one when the percentage is the same, like in this case 15%. And I want to use the formula %, not multiplying by 0.15 or 0.10. Maybe this is easier than we think.

For instance, I have:

```
10    15  15% of 10     answer
20    15  15% of 20     answer
50    15  15% of 50     answer
76    15  15% of 76     answer
90    10  10% of 90     answer
100   15  15% of 100    answer
```

I hope you understand my English; it is not my first language.

Comment: Your English seems okay, but the example is not. Please edit the question to give a complete example, including input and desired output.

Comment: Are you saying you want it to literally say "15% of 10" as text, or simply to calculate that answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at it. I suppose you want to have 15% of your data so that your table becomes this:

| Line/Row | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | My data | 15% of my data |
| 2 | 10 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 20 | 3 |
| 4 | 50 | 7 |
| 5 | 76 | 11.4 |

If that's the case, go to the cell "B2" and add the formula: =(A2*0.15)
You can then drag down the corner of the cell "B2" and excel (or calc) will adapt the formula automatically.

EDIT: Jim K. also suggested a better approach which would allow you to change the "fixed" percentage if needed be.

| Line/Row | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | My data | 0.15 |
| 2 | 10 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 20 | 3 |
| 4 | 50 | 7 |
| 5 | 76 | 11.4 |

The formula in cell "B2" would be: =(A2*$B$1)
You could then change the formatting of the cell as he suggested and you'd see percentages. As for other methods, drag the corner of "B2" down to copy the formula.

If instead you want your percentages to change according to a value you had already set in a column, replace 0.15 by that cell.
Example:

| Line/Row | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | My data | My percentages | My result |
| 2 | 10 | 15 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 20 | 15 | 3 |
| 4 | 50 | 50 | 25 |
| 5 | 76 | 100 | 76 |

In which case, the formula would need to be in the cell "C1" and should read: =(A2*B2/100)
Then select the corner of "C1" and drag it down.

Comment: How do you do that table here in Stackexchange, you are a genious.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to fill down `=A1*B$1/100`, with cells B2 to B4 empty. The `$` means that row 1 in the second part of the formula is *fixed* — the reference won't adjust as the formula is filled.

In that case, it would be simpler to change the value in column B to an actual percentage, `0.15`, which you can optionally change to display as `15%` with cell number formatting.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0.15 | =A1*B$1 |
| 20 |  | =A2*B$1 |

**EDIT**:

Here is a solution that makes it so you only have to enter the percentage when it changes. The complex `LOOKUP` parameters are a common trick to find the last non-empty cell.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 15% | =A1*LOOKUP(2;1/(B1:B$1<>"");B1:B$1) |
| 20 |  | 3 |
| 50 |  | 7.5 |
| 76 |  | 11.4 |
| 90 | 10% | 9 |
| 100 | 15% | **drag formula down from C1 to fill this column** =A6*LOOKUP(2;1/(B$1:B6<>"");B$1:B6) |

Comment: The problem is that I need to learn how to use % function. Can you give me an example using it in something similar to this case?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. kbftech and I have tried to guess, but you have not provided any more information.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. In librecalc you have a button "%", I want to use that function.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are struggling with 15% because 0.15 is the same value. In Calc, you can write the number either way, and you can format the percentage in *Format > Cells*. Regardless, I've added another answer to match the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a whole number (x) to a percentage (y), divide by 100.
If `x = 15`, then `y = 15 ÷ 100 = 15%` (or represented differently `0.15`)

Here are some screenshots of how I did it in LibreOffice Calc

Image showing formula -
[image: Image showing formula]

Image showing answers -
[image: Image showing answers]

Image showing answers after clicking on <kbd>**%**</kbd> symbol -
[image: Image showing answers with percentages]

The  <kbd>**%**</kbd> button changes the way a cell is displayed, but does not alter the contents of the cell itself.
When <kbd>**%**</kbd> button is clicked, you are instructing LibreOffice to change how the number is interpreted.
`1` becomes `100%` (because `100% of 1 = 1`; `1 = 100/100`) and `15` becomes `1500.00%` (because `1500% of 1 = 15`; `15 = 1500/100`).

See image below for example -
[image: Image showing how percentages of numbers are shown]

Visit LibreOffice help page [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-US/text/scalc/02/02140000.html) for more examples